# PySpark sum all the values of Map column into a new column

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
ID           col
1            [item1 -> 0.2, Item2 -> 0.3, item3 -> 0.4]
2            [item2 -> 0.1, Item2 -> 0.7, item3 -> 0.2]
```

I want to sum of all the row wise decimal values and store into a new column

```
ID           col                                                total
1            [item1 -> 0.2, Item2 -> 0.3, item3 -> 0.4]          0.9
2            [item2 -> 0.1, Item2 -> 0.7, item3 -> 0.2]          1.0
```

My approach

```
df = df.withColumn('total', F.expr('aggregate(map_values(col),0,(acc,x) -> acc + x)'))
```

This is not working as it says, it can be applied only to int

Comment: what is the data type of `col`?

Comment: @samkart it is map <str,double>

Comment: @samkart col is Map, the value is double. sorry for that

Comment: so, when you do `printSchema()`, it says `map` against `col`? in that case, shouldn't the column look like `{item1 -> 0.2, ...}`? notice the curly bracket

Comment: @samkart  Col :  map, key : string, value : double

Comment: No, I pasted my Pyspark output as it is

Comment: You can make a slight change and specify the initial value of the `double` type.  `df = df.withColumn('total', F.expr('aggregate(map_values(col), double(0), (acc,x) -> acc + x)'))
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('map_vals', func.map_values('col')). \
    withColumn('sum_of_vals', func.expr('aggregate(map_vals, cast(0 as double), (x, y) -> x + y)'))
```

Since, your values are of `float` type, the initial value passed within the `aggregate` should match the type of the values in the array. So, casting the initial `0` to `double` instead of using `0` should work fine.

Comment: ``` Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o18081.withColumn.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'aggregate(`map_vals`, 0.0BD, lambdafunction((CAST(namedlambdavariable() AS DOUBLE) + namedlambdavariable()), namedlambdavariable(), namedlambdavariable()), lambdafunction(namedlambdavariable(), namedlambdavariable()))' due to data type mismatch: argument 3 requires decimal(1,1) type, however, 'lambdafunction((CAST(namedlambdavariable() AS DOUBLE) + namedlambdavariable()), namedlambdavariable(), namedlambdavariable())' is of double type.;;``` @samkart

Comment: It is still not working, can you edit the answer if possible?

Comment: edited to reflect the data type